# Get max record for each type in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image]

I have a table as shown in above image. I am having rows in that for various Systems and its resource type e.g. RAM, HDD,CPU of  etc. Also, for each Resource Type i am having a column R_ID which is actually (RevisionId) & is incrementing by 1 on each update.

Sample: below I have few records with columns

> (Machinename->Resource->R_Id->MemorySizeInGb)

1. cbedev ->HDD->1->2048
2. cbedev->HDD->2->1024
3. cbedev->HDD->3->1024
4. cbedev->HDD->4->1024
5. cbedev->HDD->5->1024
6. cbedev->HDD->6->1024
7. dev1 ->RAM->1->2048
8. dev1->RAM->2->1024
9. dev1->RAM->3->1024
10. cbed2->HDD->1->1024
11. cbed2->HDD->2->1024

What I want is, to get the `MemorySizeInGb` of the highest R_ID record of each machines. So from above, my desired out put will be (kindly note, I only need the size, below is just to make the things clear).

- cbedev->HDD->6->1024
- dev1->RAM->3->1024
- cbed2->HDD->2->1024

I too have a working query, but I doubt it will not work in production with huge data. here it is

```
    SELECT TOP 1 new_resource_value
    FROM event_history_tbls
    WHERE event_history_tbls.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
    AND event_history_tbls.resource_description = 'RAM'
    AND event_history_tbls.req_dt <= @todate
    AND r_id = (
                SELECT max(r_id)
                FROM event_history_tbls t1
                WHERE t1.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                AND t1.resource_description = 'RAM'
                AND t1.req_dt <= @todate
                )
    GROUP BY new_resource_value
    ,r_id
```

Let me know, if there is more optimal solution than above.  Thanks in advance.
UPDATE

This is my actual query

```
SELECT env_name
    ,sys_fqdn_name
    ,ipv4
    ,(
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN (
                        IsNULL((
                                SELECT TOP 1 new_resource_value
                                FROM event_history_tbls
                                WHERE event_history_tbls.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                                    AND event_history_tbls.resource_description = 'RAM'
                                    AND event_history_tbls.req_dt <= @todate
                                    AND r_id = (
                                        SELECT max(r_id)
                                        FROM event_history_tbls t1
                                        WHERE t1.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                                            AND t1.resource_description = 'RAM'
                                            AND t1.req_dt <= @todate
                                        )
                                GROUP BY new_resource_value
                                    ,r_id
                                ), 0) = 0
                        )
                    THEN cast(physical_memory AS FLOAT)
                ELSE cast(IsNULL((
                                SELECT TOP 1 new_resource_value
                                FROM event_history_tbls
                                WHERE event_history_tbls.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                                    AND event_history_tbls.resource_description = 'RAM'
                                    AND event_history_tbls.req_dt <= @todate
                                    AND r_id = (
                                        SELECT max(r_id)
                                        FROM event_history_tbls t1
                                        WHERE t1.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                                            AND t1.resource_description = 'RAM'
                                            AND t1.req_dt <= @todate
                                        )
                                GROUP BY new_resource_value
                                    ,r_id
                                ), 0) AS FLOAT)
                END
            )
        ) PHYSICAL_MEMORY
    ,no_of_hdd
    ,(
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN (
                        IsNULL((
                                SELECT TOP 1 new_resource_value
                                FROM event_history_tbls
                                WHERE event_history_tbls.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                                    AND event_history_tbls.resource_description = 'HDD'
                                    AND event_history_tbls.req_dt <= @todate
                                    AND r_id = (
                                        SELECT max(r_id)
                                        FROM event_history_tbls t1
                                        WHERE t1.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                                            AND t1.resource_description = 'HDD'
                                            AND t1.req_dt <= @todate
                                        )
                                GROUP BY new_resource_value
                                    ,r_id
                                ), 0) = 0
                        )
                    THEN cast(total_size_hdd AS FLOAT)
                ELSE cast(IsNULL((
                                SELECT TOP 1 new_resource_value
                                FROM event_history_tbls
                                WHERE event_history_tbls.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                                    AND event_history_tbls.resource_description = 'HDD'
                                    AND event_history_tbls.req_dt <= @todate
                                    AND r_id = (
                                        SELECT max(r_id)
                                        FROM event_history_tbls t1
                                        WHERE t1.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                                            AND t1.resource_description = 'HDD'
                                            AND t1.req_dt <= @todate
                                        )
                                GROUP BY new_resource_value
                                    ,r_id
                                ), 0) AS FLOAT)
                END
            )
        ) TOTAL_SIZE_HDD
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN (
                    IsNULL((
                            SELECT TOP 1 new_resource_value
                            FROM event_history_tbls
                            WHERE event_history_tbls.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                                AND event_history_tbls.resource_description = 'CPU'
                                AND event_history_tbls.req_dt <= @todate
                                AND r_id = (
                                    SELECT max(r_id)
                                    FROM event_history_tbls t1
                                    WHERE t1.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                                        AND t1.resource_description = 'CPU'
                                        AND t1.req_dt <= @todate
                                    )
                            GROUP BY new_resource_value
                                ,r_id
                            ), 0) = 0
                    )
                THEN no_of_cpu
            ELSE cast(IsNULL((
                            SELECT TOP 1 new_resource_value
                            FROM event_history_tbls
                            WHERE event_history_tbls.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                                AND event_history_tbls.resource_description = 'CPU'
                                AND event_history_tbls.req_dt <= @todate
                                AND r_id = (
                                    SELECT max(r_id)
                                    FROM event_history_tbls t1
                                    WHERE t1.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name
                                        AND t1.resource_description = 'CPU'
                                        AND t1.req_dt <= @todate
                                    )
                            GROUP BY new_resource_value
                                ,r_id
                            ), 0) AS FLOAT)
            END
        ) NO_OF_CPU
    ,cpu_core_each
    ,environment
FROM sys_hdwr_dtls
WHERE UPPER(sys_hdwr_dtls.env_name) LIKE @envname
    AND UPPER(sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name) LIKE @machinename
    AND Flag = 1
```

Comment: The query in your question will not work.  This condition will fail:  `event_history_tbls.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually, its a subquery for getting RAM details only and I am having one more table running above this which is `sys_hdwr_dtls`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Row_Number`.

```
with cte_1
as
(SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Machinename,Resource ORDER BY  R_ID desc) RNO
FROM Yourtable)
SELECT *
FROM cte_1
WHERE Rno=1
```

So your script will be like below.You need to correct the Condition (`t1.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name`) which seems to be wrong.

```
;WITH cte_1
AS
    (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Machinename,Resourse ORDER BY r_id desc ) RNO
    FROM event_history_tbls
    WHERE event_history_tbls.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name -- Place proper condition (@gordon already pointed out this)
    AND event_history_tbls.resource_description = 'RAM'
    AND event_history_tbls.req_dt <= @todate)
SELECT *
FROM cte_1
WHERE RNO=1
```

Comment: Actually, its a subquery for RAM only and I am having one more table running above this which is `sys_hdwr_dtls`

Comment: with out the full script,we can't give you a proper solution.. any way .. have you tried with the given script?

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that your question is a correlated subquery, then probably the most efficient code is:

```
SELECT TOP 1 new_resource_value
FROM event_history_tbls
WHERE event_history_tbls.sys_fqdn_name = sys_hdwr_dtls.sys_fqdn_name AND
      event_history_tbls.resource_description = 'RAM' AND
      event_history_tbls.req_dt <= @todate
ORDER BY r_id DESC
```

The `GROUP BY` and subquery are not necessary.

For performance, you want an index on `event_history_tbls(sys_fqdn_name, resource_description, req_dt)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
SELECT Machinename,Resource,R_Id,MemorySizeInGb
FROM TableName t1
WHERE R_Id =( SELECT MAX(R_Id) 
              FROM TableName t2 
              WHERE t1.Machinename = t2.Machinename AND t1.Resource=t2.Resource)
```